# Rethinkdb change feed only return the changes

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

I am using rethinkdbdash in Node js connecting to the rethinkdb. 
Using the below code I get the whole document that has been changed (old and new values).

```
r.db(db).table('test')
  .changes()
  .run()
  .then(function(feed){
    feed.each(function(err, item){
      io.emit('change message', item);
    })
  })
```

I only want the field that has been changed and the new value.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the change documents on the server to get them into the form you want.  Something like this might do what you want:

```
r.table('test').changes().map(function(row) {
  return row('old_val').keys().setUnion(row('new_val').keys()).concatMap(function(key) {
    return r.branch(row('old_val')(key).ne(row('new_val')(key)).default(true),
                    [[key, row('new_val')(key).default(null)]],
                    []);
  }).coerceTo('object');
})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. 

If I run this, it will pass the object twice. Don't know why. 


It is also possible to pass the id of the document?

Comment: You can always pass the `id` by changing `row('old_val')(key).ne(row('new_val')(key))` to `key.eq('id').or(row('old_val')(key).ne(row('new_val')(key)))`

Comment: Is it possible to return another column property besides id?

I am trying to add another column called 'name' next to the column 'id' in the change fee, but can't figure it out.